# GRmetrics R package - GRfit error message

Tags: r

i'm attempting to use the GRmetric R package. I've loaded the pacckage/library and can run the test dataset (inputCaseA) included in the package just fine, but when I try and run my own data i get an error message regarding my column names:

```
Error in GRfit(Book7_v4, groupingVariables = c("cell_line", "agent")) : There must be columns named 'concentration', 'cell_count',
'cell_count__ctrl', and 'cell_count__time0' in inputData. If
initial cell count (cell_count__time0) is not available, the assay
duration and division time of cells can be used instead in columns
labeled 'treatment_duration' and 'division_time'
```

My data column names match the test dataset--they are in the same order and case. I have made sure the data type for each column is correct. I've tried rounding the data. I reinstalled the package.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Very frustrating to be stumbling at the first hurdle!

Please see below for code:

```
#install package and load library

if (!require("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
  install.packages("BiocManager")

library(tidyverse)
library(cli)
library(devtools)
library(dplyr)
library(plyr)
library(readr)
library(RColorBrewer) 
library(ggplot2)
library(GRmetrics)
library(readxl)


#test case - this works! 
data(inputCaseA)
drc_output = GRfit(inputCaseA, groupingVariables = c('cell_line','agent'))
GRdrawDRC(drc_output)

#4931 day 7 data incucyte, edited file to have T0 as one consistent value 

library(readxl)
Book7_v4 <- read_excel("Book7_v4.xlsx")
View(Book7_v4)

#the cell_count column is listed as an character but needs to be an integer 
Book7_v4$cell_count <- as.integer(Book7_v4$cell_count)

#run GRfit - extract the GR parameters - doesn't work - error in GRfit
input = GRfit(Book7_v4, groupingVariables = c('cell_line','agent'))
```